# Holonomic function closure property and approximation

Tags: combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, generating-functions

We call a function  $f(z)\in \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ holonomic if there exists a differential operator of the from
$$ a_{i}(x)(D_x)^i + \ldots+a_{0}(x)    $$ which annihilated $f(x)$. $D_{x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $a_i (x)\in \mathbb{C}(x)$ are polynomials.
For example $e^x=\sum_{d}\frac{1}{d!}x^d$ is holonomic.

The following series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}G( iz)\right)z^n \tag{*}$$ is a holonomic function in $z$ if $G(z)$ is rational.
My question is when $G(z) =e^z$ what kind of differential we obtain? We know that $e^z$ can be approximated by rational function. In that case, we get a sequence of differential equations how does it relate to help conclude existence of differential eq that annihilate $(*)$.
There are many closure properties share by holonomic function. When those properties can be carried to the function like (*)?
Any literature, reference will be helpful.

Comment: As someone familiar with generating functions and differential operators, but not too familiar with $D$-finite functions, this question is very unclear. Are you saying that $(*)$ is $D$-finite when $G(z)=e^z$, and if so how do you know? Also, is it $\sum\left(\prod_{i=1}^n G(iz)\right)z^n,$ or is it $\sum\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (G(iz)z^n)\right)$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I have done some edits to the question. Let say a holonomic differential eq is the one with a polynomial coefficient. I am saying if G(z) is rational then I know it's holonomic. I remove the  D-finite thing

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It would still be helpful to include the background behind the "$G$ is rational $\implies$ $(*)$ is holonomic" result. Is it a well known theorem, or a lemma in a niche paper? I need to understand that result before I can generalize it. Also, you ask what kind of differential you obtain when $G(z)=e^z$, which presupposes that such a differential operator exists. How do you know this to be true? If you do not, you should rephrase, something like "Can we also conclude $(*)$ is holonomic when $G(z)=e^z$. I hope these nitpicks I am making actually help.

Comment: I make some quick comments, if we given a series$ \sum_n a_n z^n $where $a_n is function in z$, if the ratio is $a_{n+1}/a_n $ is rational then we know the series will be annihilated by some holomorphic function. If G(z)= e^z it won't be holomorphic but I believe there would be differential eq with with exponential coefficient. But more than that I was wondering if we can carry on the closure properties.

Comment: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html